# Is it possible to share a variable between conftest and pytest_runtest_makereport in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I want to initialize a number and use it in pytest_runtest_makereport function.

When I initialize in `my_dict = {"num": 1}` and try to access in `pytest_runtest_makereport` I am not able to access this in `pytest_runtest_makereport`.

Is it possible How can I do it? and example would help

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: It's hard to judge without the code, but if you define my_dict as a global variable in the conftest.py module then all you need may be 'global my_dict' as one of the first lines of pytest_runtest_makereport.